# (2.3.1) Set scale of background texture to renderwindow size

Tags: c++, sfml

Just started learning SFML (so please bear with me).

I have made a RenderWindow object, and I have a image I want to fit perfectly to that window.

By searching through the documentation, I found the sf::Sprite::SetScale function. Is this the right function to do it? But how do I set the scale of the sprite to the scale of the RenderWindow, when the RenderWindow object size is set in pixels? Do I have to get the scale of the RenderWindow, and then assign the background sprite to that scale or?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 300), "Simple Game");

  sf::Texture BackgroundTexture;
  sf::Sprite background;

  //background.setScale(0.2, 0.2); <--- how?

  if(!BackgroundTexture.loadFromFile("media/background.png"))
  {
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    background.setTexture(BackgroundTexture);
  }

  while(window.isOpen())
  {
    sf::Event event;

    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
        }
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(background);
    window.display();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale factor you need is simply the ratio between the window size and the texture size. sf::Texture has a getSize function, as has sf::RenderWindow. Simply get the sizes of both, calculate the ratio and use it to set the scale of the sprite, like this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 300), "Simple Game");

  sf::Texture BackgroundTexture;
  sf::Sprite background;
  sf::Vector2u TextureSize;  //Added to store texture size.
  sf::Vector2u WindowSize;   //Added to store window size.

  if(!BackgroundTexture.loadFromFile("background.png"))
  {
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    TextureSize = BackgroundTexture.getSize(); //Get size of texture.
    WindowSize = window.getSize();             //Get size of window.

    float ScaleX = (float) WindowSize.x / TextureSize.x;
    float ScaleY = (float) WindowSize.y / TextureSize.y;     //Calculate scale.

    background.setTexture(BackgroundTexture);
    background.setScale(ScaleX, ScaleY);      //Set scale.  
  }

  while(window.isOpen())
  {
    sf::Event event;

    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
        }
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(background);
    window.display();
 }
}
```